# Find GUID of MSI Package

Tags: windows, scripting, msi, windows-installer

How can I find the GUID of an MSI package?  I would like to script the removal of a program on a large number of desktops by using:

> msiexec.exe /x *ProductCode*

Any reason why this would not work for any applications listed in "Add/Remove Programs?"

Comment: Just for the record: [**How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569) (provided the setup is installed on the machine itself - if not get hold of **Orca** from the Windows SDK or [**another packaging tool**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941)).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Try this stackoverflow.com answer instead: [**How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup) or even this one: [Find GUID From MSI File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251034/find-guid-from-msi-file)
.

---

The **Windows SDK** tool **Orca** will allow you to open and view all tables in an MSI file. Once you have the MSI open, you can either navigate to the Property table and look for the "product code" entry, or you can select "View => Summary Information..." and look for the "package code" entry. Either the package or the product guid can be used for uninstall.

See an **Orca screenshot** of how to find the product code in the MSI: [WiX - Doing a major upgrade on a multi instance install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860622/wix-doing-a-major-upgrade-on-a-multi-instance-install/22862283#22862283)

There are also **other ways** to find the GUID:

> **`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`**
>
> **`HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`**
>
> **`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`**

It still appears you have to download the MSI SDK to obtain Orca. If you don't have access to Orca and can't be bothered downloading the SDK, any viewer capable of reading a MSSQL database file (com stuctured storage file), should be able to open the MSI file and view the contents. Make a copy of the MSI before opening it in a viewer and open the copy. Just to be sure. Once open you navigate to the Property table and look for the product GUID.

**UPDATE**: [**A list of free MSI viewers (towards bottom)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546).

Also check these posts on **stackoverflow.com** with information on how to uninstall via **Powershell**:

- [How to uninstall with msiexec using product id guid without .msi file present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491631/how-to-uninstall-with-msiexec-using-product-id-guid-without-msi-file-present/21502621#21502621)
- [Uninstall script not performing correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364258/uninstall-script-not-performing-correctly/25374825#25374825)
- [**How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569)
- [Find GUID From MSI File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251034/find-guid-from-msi-file/29938049#29938049)

Comment: It can be a real hassle to get hold of Orca.exe since it is only available as part of the SDK. If anyone is in a rush, I am happy to email you a copy. At the moment Microsoft seems to have put it available only in the full SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en . But as you know Microsoft changes things almost daily.

Comment: The SDK is fairly simple to get as well...but you do have to download more. A search can also turn up other MSI editors, such as InstEdit.

Comment: You can use SuperOrca instead of Orca. Does the same thing and is much easier to catch.

Comment: Since `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` ist a merge of  `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes` and `HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes` the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products`  resides actually in `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products` resp. maybe its `HKCU` counterpart.

Answer (score 7):

It is a registry key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{<guid>}
```

or if the platform is x64 and the application is 32-bit:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{<guid>}
```

Comment: Not only that, but the msiexec command is actually contained in a subkey, "UninstallString!"

Answer (score 4):

There is also a very helpful GUI tool called Product Browser which appears to be made by Microsoft or at least an employee of Microsoft.

It can be found on Github here [Product Browser](https://github.com/suyouquan/SQLSetupTools)

The latest version as of (10/9/20) is available [here](https://github.com/suyouquan/SQLSetupTools#product-browser-22)

I personally had a very easy time locating the GUID I needed with this.

Answer (score 3):

A light-weight freeware tool like [InstEd](http://www.instedit.com) can be used.  Just open the MSI, on the "Tables" tab, click on "Property" on the left, then on the right, locate "ProductCode".

Answer (score 3):

In Powershell you can query wmi for installations

```
$program = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Product | ? {$_.Name -eq "Java Auto Updater"} 
$program.IdentifyingNumber #IdentifyingNumber is the guid
```

example to repair

```
msiexec /fa $program.IdentifyingNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

[Revision Number Summary Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371255%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> [T]he Revision Number Summary property
>   lists the product code GUIDs [...]

Comment: That's a pretty vague answer, but I did find what you were referring to. Thanks