# SCCM: Detection Method for Exchange Server 2013 Management Tools

Tags: exchange-2013, sccm

Trying to roll out Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 Management Tools via SCCM's Application Management. Distribution and installation works fine, but the Softwarecenter Client completes installation with an error, saying it cannot detect the installed application (SCCM Error 0x87D00324 [-2016410844]).

Would like to detect the management tools by looking at the corresponding product code (GUID).

What I tried so far to find that product code:

- Searched Windows-Registry (after installation) in:
  **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**
  and in:
  **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products**
  ([see this answer)](https://serverfault.com/a/274673/264905)
- Searched the WMIC Product list
  ([as per here)](http://bitwyze.net/?p=204)

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Solved" it...

Apparently, the .msi-product code which is required for the detection method "windows installer" has to be surrounded with curly brackets. Didn't know about that since it's not mentioned in the configuration window and it's also not mentioned anywhere in the corresponding technet-pages:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg682159.aspx#BKMK_Step4

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb632336.aspx